# How to drill down through multiple polygons/points in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, overlapping-features

I have a layer that has multiple polygons sitting on top of each other, is there a way to easily scroll through those polygons that overlap each other?

Comment: perform Spatial Query,by selecting any two polygons.

Comment: Do you want to do it visually or programmatically?

Comment: til_b I would like to do it visually if possible, but would be happy with any method where I can identify the polygon(s) I am looking for.

Answer (score 2):

You've probably figured this out by now but you can use the Query Builder (from *Layer* > *Query...*) to filter the polygons/points you want to be shown depending on their attributes.